# How to run TensorFlow Serving as an Azure Container Instance and pass a docker command

Tags: azure, tensorflow-serving, azure-container-instances, docker-run, docker-command

I usually run TensorFlow Serving Docker image using this command:

```
docker run -p 8500:8500 \
--mount type=bind,source=/mnt/docker/models,target=/models \
--mount type=bind,source=/mnt/docker/configs/models.config,target=/models/models.config \
-t tensorflow/serving \
--model_config_file=/models/models.config &
sleep 2m
```

I want to deploy the same image from Docker Hub on Azure as a Container Instance using `az create` and pass the same command line arguments as above

I've given it multiple tries and got several errors

e.g. `run: 1: run: docker: not found`

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does the docker command work well? Does the parameter `--model_config_file=/models/models.config` really work?

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way of doing this is through command line, either from your OS terminal or from azure portal. docker is not directly accessible AFAIK.

> skip this step if using portal

**1 Login**

From OS Terminal (you need to have `azure cli` installed);

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

```
az login
```

**2 Creating the container**

from this point on, you can use same commands from the portal and the terminal.

then you got to create your container using azure commands

```
    az container create 
        -g {RESOURCE GROUP TO USE} // you'll need a resource group to contain the container group
        -n {NAME FOR CONTAINER GROUP} // this is just a name for the container group
        --image tensorflow/serving // guessing this is what you would like to mount to docker
        --ip-address public  //may need to access it externally at start
        --ports 8500 8501  // you will need to access to REST OR gRPC or both
        --cpu 1 // core count, in whole numbers
        --memory 2.5 // float in GBs
        --dns-name-label my-tf-server // to have a static address over the network
```

**3 Mounting drive**

if you need to mount an azure file system to read the models from, these will be what you need

```
        --azure-file-volume-account-name {ACC NAME} 
        --azure-file-volume-account-key {ACC KEY} // you probably should use an env variable to make it secure
        --azure-file-volume-share-name {my-file-system} // file share name to mount
        --azure-file-volume-mount-path /models // path to mount to
```

**4 Custom startup command**

And this is in case you need to throw in a custom startup command, to load a custom model or config file

```
        --command-line "tensorflow_model_server --port=8500 --rest_api_port=8501 --model_config_file=/models/models.config"
```

The rest is handled by azure itself :) for more info, you can check this out;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-start

**5 More on tf-serving flags**

here is the full list of flags that you can use with the `--command-line` flag to the model server

```
usage: tensorflow_model_server
Flags:
    --port=8500                         int32   Port to listen on for gRPC API
    --grpc_socket_path=""               string  If non-empty, listen to a UNIX socket for gRPC API on the given path. Can be either relative or absolute path.
    --rest_api_port=0                   int32   Port to listen on for HTTP/REST API. If set to zero HTTP/REST API will not be exported. This port must be different than the one specified in --port.
    --rest_api_num_threads=16           int32   Number of threads for HTTP/REST API processing. If not set, will be auto set based on number of CPUs.
    --rest_api_timeout_in_ms=30000      int32   Timeout for HTTP/REST API calls.
    --enable_batching=false             bool    enable batching
    --batching_parameters_file=""       string  If non-empty, read an ascii BatchingParameters protobuf from the supplied file name and use the contained values instead of the defaults.
    --model_config_file=""              string  If non-empty, read an ascii ModelServerConfig protobuf from the supplied file name, and serve the models in that file. This config file can be used to specify multiple models to serve and other advanced parameters including non-default version policy. (If used, --model_name, --model_base_path are ignored.)
    --model_name="default"              string  name of model (ignored if --model_config_file flag is set)
    --model_base_path=""                string  path to export (ignored if --model_config_file flag is set, otherwise required)
    --max_num_load_retries=5            int32   maximum number of times it retries loading a model after the first failure, before giving up. If set to 0, a load is attempted only once. Default: 5
    --load_retry_interval_micros=60000000   int64   The interval, in microseconds, between each servable load retry. If set negative, it doesn't wait. Default: 1 minute
    --file_system_poll_wait_seconds=1   int32   Interval in seconds between each poll of the filesystem for new model version. If set to zero poll will be exactly done once and not periodically. Setting this to negative value will disable polling entirely causing ModelServer to indefinitely wait for a new model at startup. Negative values are reserved for testing purposes only.
    --flush_filesystem_caches=true      bool    If true (the default), filesystem caches will be flushed after the initial load of all servables, and after each subsequent individual servable reload (if the number of load threads is 1). This reduces memory consumption of the model server, at the potential cost of cache misses if model files are accessed after servables are loaded.
    --tensorflow_session_parallelism=0  int64   Number of threads to use for running a Tensorflow session. Auto-configured by default.Note that this option is ignored if --platform_config_file is non-empty.
    --tensorflow_intra_op_parallelism=0 int64   Number of threads to use to parallelize the executionof an individual op. Auto-configured by default.Note that this option is ignored if --platform_config_file is non-empty.
    --tensorflow_inter_op_parallelism=0 int64   Controls the number of operators that can be executed simultaneously. Auto-configured by default.Note that this option is ignored if --platform_config_file is non-empty.
    --ssl_config_file=""                string  If non-empty, read an ascii SSLConfig protobuf from the supplied file name and set up a secure gRPC channel
    --platform_config_file=""           string  If non-empty, read an ascii PlatformConfigMap protobuf from the supplied file name, and use that platform config instead of the Tensorflow platform. (If used, --enable_batching is ignored.)
    --per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.000000  float   Fraction that each process occupies of the GPU memory space the value is between 0.0 and 1.0 (with 0.0 as the default) If 1.0, the server will allocate all the memory when the server starts, If 0.0, Tensorflow will automatically select a value.
    --saved_model_tags="serve"          string  Comma-separated set of tags corresponding to the meta graph def to load from SavedModel.
```